# HttpWebRequest works with windows form but not with Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I need to call HTTPS POST service from WEB API method.
I am using HttpWebRequest to call this API, however i am getting error as
"A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond x.x.x.x:443"

**When I tried to call this API in Windows Form then it works well.**

```
HttpWebRequest r = null; 
HttpWebResponse rsp = null; 
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12; 
r = (HttpWebRequest)System.Net.WebRequest.Create("url"); 
String d = "Serialize JSON" 
r.Method = "POST"; 
r.ContentType = "application/json"; 
StreamWriter wr = new StreamWriter(r.GetRequestStream()); 
wr.WriteLine(d); 
wr.Close(); 
rsp = (HttpWebResponse)r.GetResponse();
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(rsp.GetResponseStream()); 
String dd = reader.ReadToEnd();
```

Comment: Please show the example code for both Web API & Windows Forms calling, which may help identify issue.

Comment: Why don't you use HttpClient class?

Comment: Sample code working for Windows Form. Same code is not working for Web API
HttpWebRequest r = null; HttpWebResponse rsp = null;
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
r = (HttpWebRequest)System.Net.WebRequest.Create("https://url");
String d = "Serialize JSON"
r.Method = "POST";
r.ContentType = "application/json";
StreamWriter wr = new StreamWriter(r.GetRequestStream());
wr.WriteLine(d);
wr.Close();
rsp = (HttpWebResponse)r.GetResponse();StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(rsp.GetResponseStream());
String dd = reader.ReadToEnd();

Answer (score 0):

Might be because you are trying to use SSL, from the last part - x.x.x.x:443. My understanding is that 443 is used for SSL. Happy for someone to correct me if I incorrect.

Have a look at the following, this may help you out:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/working-with-ssl-in-web-api